# UnitOfWork Addasync method doesn't return stored entity

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, unit-of-work

I'm using Entity Framework with `AuditableEntity` to build my database
[I declare my entities like this with the id type (int)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pec6x.png)

First I used `string` as the type of the entities Id then I changed it to `int` previously when an entity is stored the `UnitOfWork.AddAsync()` method returned the stored entity with the auto-generated `Id` but after the change it doesn't

[As you can see here the stored entity id returns 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxBfz.png)

Comment: We can't guess what your own custom code does. EF doesn't need extra Entity base classes or Unit Of Work. The DbContext class itself is the Unit-Of-Work and multi-entity Repository. Changes are committed/persisted **only** when `SaveChanges` is called, in a single internal transaction. `Add` doesn't insert anything, it starts tracking the previously detached entity as part of the UoW, in the `Added` state

Comment: `UnitOfWork.AddAsync()` calls the `context.SaveChanges` inside of it to commit the changes i used it just before and it was working fine, I resolved the problem by commiting the changes but i wanted to know why it worked before but it doesn't anymore

Comment: I repeat, we can't guess what *your* custom, unconventional, code looks like, what it looked before and what it looks like now. You even named your own method `AddAsync` which does something completely different than what `DbContext.AddAsync` does. I call the code "unconventional" because EF Core simply doesn't need extra UoW and calling `SaveChanges` inside a method called `AddAsync` is a major bug. `SaveChanges` persists *all* changes. That `AddAsync` may be executing 42 DELETEs and 67 UPDATEs along with 11 INSERTs

Comment: Is the question why a `string Id` doesn't get the value of a database-generated `bigint` IDENTITY column? Because that property wasn't configured as database-generated in the first place. EF uses a number of [conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations#primary-keys) so you don't have to explicitly specify everything in a model, eg properties named `Id` or `{Type}Id` are uses as PKs unless specified otherwise. Only numeric/GUID IDs are assumed to be db-generated by default. `string` is always the wrong type for numeric data

Comment: That means that a `string Id` is unconventional by definition - it doesn't follow EF's conventions for autogenerated primary keys: `By convention, non-composite primary keys of type short, int, long, or Guid are set up to have values generated for inserted entities if a value isn't provided by the application.`